# How to align active tab center in android Sliding Tab Layout

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have 12 items in android sliding tab layout + view pager. While sliding from left to right, selected tab should be center same as play store. Please help me how to do that. In my application active tab is always left of the screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) in your project (that is what Google Play app is using). Looks like you are using normal tabs instead.

Comment: No, I have used SlidingTabLayout class which is provided by google as a sample class for sliding tab layout. Also i have tried PagerTabStrip it doesn't allow you to slide tab title like play store. SlidingTabLayout is extended HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: I see. Looking at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk) from Android developers, you can see this is not the expected behavior. In order to get the effect that Google Play has, you have to use **PagerTabStrip**. It is super easy to implement, checkout [this tutorial](http://codetheory.in/android-pagertabstrip-pagertitlestrip-viewpager/).

Comment: Thanks Mark. I got the issue resolved below is my answer.

Comment: The [SmartTabLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout) does this very nicely.

Answer (score 13):

My approach differs a bit of the [Shripad Bhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1101420/shripad-bhat) solution, which bounce the tab at the end of the slide.

Here's my workaround...

Changes to `onPageScrolled` method:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
        return;
    }

    mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

    View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
    int selectedOffset = (selectedTitle == null) ? 0 : selectedTitle.getWidth();
    int nextTitlePosition = position + 1;
    View nextTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(nextTitlePosition);
    int nextOffset = (nextTitle == null) ? 0 : nextTitle.getWidth();
    int extraOffset = (int)(0.5F * (positionOffset * (float)(selectedOffset + nextOffset)));
    scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

    if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
    }
}
```

Changes to `scrollToTab` method:

```
private int mLastScrollTo;

private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null && selectedChild.getMeasuredWidth() != 0) {

        int targetScrollX = ((positionOffset + selectedChild.getLeft()) - getWidth() / 2) + selectedChild.getWidth() / 2;

        if (targetScrollX != mLastScrollTo) {
            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
            mLastScrollTo = targetScrollX;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you, it's awesome. But how to make first tab item in center?

Comment: I'm not able to find `onPageScrolled`, I'm using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with `TabLayout` of design library

Comment: Hello @NickUnuchek did u managed to make first tab in center..?? please help

Answer (score 3):

Google Has provided sample for [sliding tab layout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html). But in the implementation of SlidingTabLayout class, it was not designed for center align the selected tab. I have modify the scroll method to make the selected/active tab center of the screen. Here is the code change:

Class Name: [SlidingTabLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)

Line Number: 241, scrollToTab{}

Updated Method:

```
private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
            // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
            targetScrollX -= (getWidth()-selectedChild.getWidth())/2;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to get the display for measure the width of the scrollview, just call getWidth() ;) i.e.: targetScrollX -= (getWidth()-selectedChild.getWidth())/2;

Comment: Yuri Heupa, Updated the answer. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: +1 It works :) However, there's a slight jerk at the end in efforts to place it in the center. The below fixes it. :) Good job though.

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem as well. tabLayout provides only tabContentStart option, needed both sides:

```
public class CenteringTabLayout extends TabLayout {
public CenteringTabLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CenteringTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CenteringTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    View firstTab = ((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);
    View lastTab = ((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(((ViewGroup)getChildAt(0)).getChildCount()-1);
    ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(getChildAt(0), (getWidth()/2) - (firstTab.getWidth()/2),0,(getWidth()/2) - (lastTab.getWidth()/2),0);
}
}
```

Comment: your code is throwing an exception on the row that is using ViewCompat, could you please explain your code a little bit more so I can understand what you really want to do.

Comment: I extended android.support.design.widget.TabLayout. First child is SlidingTabStrip and every tab is one of its children and I'm trying to set padding to this SlidingTabStrip
But even mine does not center the last tabs corectly. Still didnt find why.