# Android TabLayout with active tab always at center, just like in Play Newsstand app

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, google-play-newsstand

In `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`, how to make the active tab always appear at the center, just like in **Play Newsstand** app, as shown below.

The first and last tab should also appear at the center.

[image: Play Newsstand]

[image: Play Newsstand]

I tried using padding on the TabLayout. It is not working. This is the code that I wrote:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/yellow"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="#EEE"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingLeft="90dp"
            android:paddingRight="90dp"
            />
```

In this case, the tabIndicator will also shift 90dp from left. It should remain at the center independent of the padding.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768239/how-to-align-active-tab-center-in-android-sliding-tab-layout) SO question and answer.

Comment: hello did you managed to do this..??

Comment: [MaterialViewPager](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager) project on github might help you..

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36886331/651770

Could be solved by tabContentStart, but if you want to center both sides of Tablayout, you need to extend this class and set the padding by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late, but you can try using this library :

https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip

This can be done as they said :

Include the following dependency in your build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.1.1'
```

Or add the library as a project. I tried to send a pull request, but looks like the original developer doesn't maintain it anymore.

Include the PagerSlidingTabStrip widget in your layout. This should usually be placed above the ViewPager it represents.

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

In your onCreate method (or onCreateView for a fragment), bind the widget to the ViewPager:

```
// Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

// Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks it helps! I hope there won't be any compatibility issues in the future because it says in the Github repository : *This library is not maintained anymore and there will be no further releases. For most of the cases you can use TabLayout instead of this library.*