# Tabs from Tablayout no display on a center of the screen

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I use Tablayout and create tabs dynamically. Then the app selects a proper tab by code:

```
myTablayout.getTabAt(int_position).select();
```

But I have a problem: selected tab doesn't display on the screen (if he isn't one of first) and I need to scroll for his reaching.

[image]

What can I do that a selected tab display in a center of the screen? (exclude tabs which on edges, of course, but they just must display on the screen exactly)

I don't use Viewpager. It does not need for my task.

**XML myTablout:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/quick_tournament2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Comment: please provide your tab layout xml code

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768239/how-to-align-active-tab-center-in-android-sliding-tab-layout

Comment: @kamalverma I did, see the end of my post, please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android center align the selected tab in tablayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083638/android-center-align-the-selected-tab-in-tablayout)