# Android - only display tabs before and after the selected tab

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, center, spacing

I'm trying to have a tab layout like the CNN app, where the tab is centered and only the tabs before and after are shown, each cropped to show half of the text like this:
[cnn tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maK4a.jpg)

I managed to always have the selected tab centered thanks to SO posts like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768239/how-to-align-active-tab-center-in-android-sliding-tab-layout)

and currently the app looks like [my tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woa6Z.jpg)

but i can't figure out how to space out (and crop) the tab before and after the center tab.

TabLayout_tabPadding attribute doesn't seem to work, and there are different screen sizes and device orientations to consider.

my tablayout class is:

```
public class CenteringTabLayout extends TabLayout {
private Typeface mTypeface;

public CenteringTabLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CenteringTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CenteringTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    View firstTab = ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0);
    View lastTab = ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(((ViewGroup) getChildAt(0)).getChildCount() - 1);

    if(firstTab!=null)
        ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(getChildAt(0), (getWidth() / 2) - (firstTab.getWidth() / 2), 0, (getWidth() / 2) - (lastTab.getWidth() / 2), 0);
}

@Override
public void addOnTabSelectedListener(@NonNull OnTabSelectedListener listener) {
    super.addOnTabSelectedListener(listener);
}

@Override
public void addTab(@NonNull Tab tab) {
    super.addTab(tab);
    ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
    ViewGroup tabView = (ViewGroup) mainView.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());

    int tabChildCount = tabView.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < tabChildCount; i++) {
        View tabViewChild = tabView.getChildAt(i);
        if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(mTypeface, Typeface.BOLD);
        }
    }
}
```

and i am using the following dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

I am a bit new to all of this so any help is greatly appreciated.